# Choosing different versions of Zend Framework to load using Zend_Loader and it's issues

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, require-once, zend-autoloader

Okay, so, I wanna be able to choose different versions of Zend Framework (and other frameworks) using `Zend_Loader`. Well, the code isn't tricky at all, but the problem is, there are so many `require_once` lines in the framework itself that would practically make the autoloader useless.

The Zend directory has to be in the include_path which makes it a bit difficult to keep it there and also, all the `require_once` lines with non-absolute paths will have quite an impact on the application's performance, specially with my app which uses *a lot* of Zend classes on for processing each request.

I could strip out all the require_once lines manually or automatically, but I just have to do it all over again with each new 1.x.x release.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just change your include path to the correct version. For example I have a constant ZEND_PATH which is added to my include path. Prior to this, I will then define the ZEND_PATH based on the environment determination code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping `require_once`s is not that hard, just running one line of code (saved as a [script](http://gogs.info/2008/10/removing-require_once-calls-from-zend-framework/)).

See [this thread on Nabble](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Loader-Autoloader-setZfPath-application-ini-won-t-ever-work-td1598759.html) for switching Zend Framework versions.

Comment: Yeah, maybe that's the only best practice on this!
Thanks pal :)

Answer (score 1):

See also native ZF support as of 1.10:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.zf-version